# Error When Creating an ERC20 Token Using Remix IDE

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20, remix

I've been going at it for hours trying to create my token, but everytime I click "create" on Remix, it says:

> Invalid JSON RPC response: 
>   {"id":11,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}}

I've done this before and it worked. I'm getting really annoyed! I hate using Truffle as well, so I try to use this.

Comment: Hard to help without seeing code and inputs, but this usually happens when you don’t put quotes around your string and address parameters.

Comment: It works fine when deploying to a test network, but the minute I try to deploy to the main network, it says this error.

Comment: As I stated in the previous comment, it would really help if you posted your contract and the input you're trying to send. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That wouldn't help because the input and contract code won't matter. When I try to deploy to Rinkeby network, it works. When I try to deploy to the main network, it doesn't. The code doesn't seem to be the issue.